# det $A = $ det $B$ and det $U= 1\,$ , so $\,A = UB$

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $A$ and $B$ are invertible $n\times n$ matrices.  Prove that
$\det A=\det B$ if and only if $A=UB$, where $U$ is a matrix with $\det U=1$.

Showing that $A = UB$ implies equal determinants is easy, but I'm stuck on the converse. Any help?

**I want to show the following:**

$$\det A = \det B \implies \exists U, \det U = 1 \mid A = UB$$

Comment: I showed this in my answer below.

Comment: The problem statement has omitted some very important words, perhaps believing its readers would fill in the blanks. Those words are "there exists a $U$ such that."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about $U = A B^{-1}$. Then $\det U = (\det A) (\det B^{-1}) = (\det A) (\det B)^{-1} = 1 $.

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to prove

Comment: What do you mean by converse then? The above shows that if $\det A = \det B $ (and $A,B$ are invertible) then there exists a $U$ with $\det U = 1$ such that $A = UB$.

Comment: No it doesn't, it says "$\det A = \det B \iff A = UB$" where $\det U$ just happens to be equal to 1.

Comment: I don't see how this proves it then, all I see is that you're showing $\det U = 1$. :s

Comment: You might be misunderstanding what the (converse of the) problem is saying. It's asking to you show that given $\det A = \det B$, *there exists* a $U$ with $\det U = 1$ such that $A = UB$. Once you find a $U$ that works, you're done. It's not asking you to show that $A = UB$ *for all* $U$ with $\det U = 1$: that would be false.

Comment: @snario: But your problem asks for you to show that given $\det A=\det B$ and $A,B$ invertible there exists a $U$ such that $A=UB$ and $\det U=1$. This answer gives an explicit example of a $U$, in terms of $A$ and $B$, such  that $A=UB$ and $\det U=1$. Giving an example of such a $U$ is one way of proving such a $U$ exists.

Comment: If $\det A = \det B$ and $A,B$ are invertible, then the above shows that the matrix $U = A B^{-1}$ satisfies $\det  =1$ and $A = UB$. That **is** the converse, whether you like it or not.

Comment: Hm, ok, thank you, I must have misunderstood

Comment: Snario, I think copper's answer wraps this up: define $\,U:=AB^{-1}\,$ , then: (1) Indeed $\,A=UB\,$ , and (2) Indeed $\,\det U=1\,$, just as show above in the answer...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** Find $U$ explicitly!

**Hint 2:** $A = AI$.

**Hint 3:** How else can you write $I$?

Once you find a $U$ that satisfies $A = UB$, you should be able to use properties of the determinant and your hypothesis $\det A = \det B$ to show that $\det U = 1$.

Comment: 1) I'm starting with det $A$ = det $B$, but $U = AB^{-1}$
2) Yes.
3) $AA^{-1}, BB^{-1}, UU^{-1}$

Comment: Right, so you've found that if $U$ exists, it must be $AB^{-1}$. You show that what you've found for $U$ a) does indeed work and b) has determinant $1$ by using $\det A = \det B$.